# SQL Procedure to get row number to determine 'Rank'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table which contains a column called 'Score'. I want to write a procedure which loops through all rows in this table, and determines where out of all rows, each specific row ranks i.e biggest score is rank 1, smallest score = n.

This is my poor attempt so far:

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Rank INT = 0;
    DECLARE @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;


    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT UserID FROM tblMember
    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @UserID
    --loop through all users
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @Rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Score DESC) FROM tblDetails WHERE UserID = @UserID;
    PRINT @Rank 
    Print ' For '
    Print @UserID;

    UPDATE tblDetails SET Rank = @Rank WHERE UserID = @UserID; 

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @UserID
    END
END
```

Unfortauntely this effort ranks each entry as 1 - probably becuase the query has the WHERE clause refining the result set. But I cannot determine what the correct query should be!

Comment: Is userid primary key?

Comment: What is the relationship between member and details? One to Many? Please provide the `create table` for all tables involved and also show us desired results when two users have the same score.

Comment: One to One is the relationship. tblMember has UserID and other fields are irrelevant. tblDetails has a foreignKey for UserID and Score

Comment: UserID is a primary key yeah!

Comment: So what should happen if Anne and Bob have score 100 and Charles and David have score 50. What are the desired results?

Answer (score 6):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY score DESC) rn
        FROM    tblDetail
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     rank = rn
```

Comment: I am struggling to see how this fits into my previous procedure - but it is obviously correct. Can you do me a favor and post an integrated completed example based upon my original example procedure?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy: this is an integrated completed example based upon your original procedure. I've just taken the intended logic from these and put it into a single query.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy: if you have a different `userId` in each row, it does indeed. Do you need an overall score? Please update your question with some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct query you want is:

```
with toupdate as (
      select d.*,
             row_number() over (order by score desc) as seqnum
      from tblDetails
        )
update toupdate
    set [rank] = seqnum;
```

I used `row_number()` because your example does.  You might want `rank()` or `dense_rank()` if you want scores with the same value to have the same rank:

```
with toupdate as (
      select d.*,
             rank() over (order by score desc) as seqnum
      from tblDetails
        )
update toupdate
    set [rank] = seqnum;
```

The important difference is that there is no `partition by` clause in the query.

Answer (score 0):

may be basing on the userid you are trying to update or increment the rank column..So as per my understanding what ever the Userid = 1 you want to update Rank column

```
declare @t INT;
SELECT @t =  MAX(Userid) From tblDetails 
;
    with cte(w) as
(select 1 
        UNION ALL
Select Userid + 1 
                From 
        tblDetails where Userid < @t)
UPdate tblDetails 
set [Rank]=cte.w 
        FROM cte 
INNER JOIN tblDetails  S
ON S.Userid = cte.w
```